# python - file container

Tags: python, rest, amazon-s3, containers

i need to handle a lot of files and i dont want to worry about their filenames etc.

So the idea is i sent a file Test.png to an external db/rest api etc. with python and i am getting back an uuid for this file.
The next time my script does need this file it calls this external services with uuid and does get back this file :)
It does sound like amazon s3 ;) But i need something running  on linux (what i would prefer) or windows and it should be open source. I dont need something special and very easy to use (out of the box). Oh and no big data solution, the amount of data would be around 5 gb
My file processing language is Python 3.6

Does someone know a good solution here?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of search, i found something :) I want to share this:

https://minio.io/

Object Storage, can be ran inside docker etc. and has a client library for python, just perfekt for me :)